# SQLite Insert Into command not working---no error in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, insert

Here is the line of code that calls the InsertInto Sub and the InsertInto Sub itself.  Basic stuff, should work with no issues, but it doesn't.  It goes through, no errors and executes the command but the row never gets added to the table.  I also have a Bulk Insert I wrote that has inserted many rows of data previously before into Tables which I know works and have tried that as well and still no luck.

Is there something special that SQLite needs to insert rows into a table? I have checked the SQLite documentation and the INSERT INTO statement is exactly as they have shown on their site. Unsure what else to do with this, as the insert works locally in a tempDT table if I try it there.  I mean I could load the table, drop it and then create a new table after I insert the row, but I shouldn't have to do all that.  This is a simple, basic command and it SHOULD work...and before someone says to try writing it out normally without the $ implementation of the string, I already have done that trying several different methods including the "normal" one and hat hasn't worked either.  I've also not used variables for data and just used one word hardcoded strings for values and that didn't work either.

```
SQLTables.InsertInto(MyDB, "SaveGames", $"INSERT INTO SaveGames(FileName,SaveGameJSONString) VALUES ('{fileName}', '{model}')")


Public Sub InsertInto(dbName As String, tableName As String, SQLCmd As String, Optional ByVal myFilePath As String = "")
        Dim Conn As New SQLiteConnection()
        GetConnectionString(dbName, Conn, myFilePath)
        Using Conn
            Dim SQL As String = SQLCmd
            Dim Cmd As New SQLiteCommand(SQL, Conn)
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: what is the current value of MyDB, and why is myFilePath blank?

Comment: Don't you need to open the connection?

Comment: ha....good point bugs............

Comment: That is not the right way to implement `Using`

Comment: Current value of myDB is "Football" and the FilePath is blank because its in the default directory...that is if for some reason I have to set the path to a different directory for the DB.  Connection string is working is has been the same for almost a year now and I have loaded, created and done numerous bulk inserts on tables with it, just not done any single inserts...

Comment: OK, now this is really strange.  It appears to be saving it to an "in-memory" version of the database but not the one on the harddrive.  When I run it, it runs without error.  If I run it again while the program is still active, I see the row in there.  It isn't writing it to the TempDT database because that is still only 1 row once it finishes running and on calling it again it initializes a new datatable that is empty.  Once it loads the DT again, that row is in there.  However, when I go and check the HD DB, the row isn't there.  If I close the program, the row doesn't get saved to HD...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `GetConnectionString` method actually does but it should return a connection string that you pass to the constructor of the `SQLiteConnection` class.

Then the following should work:

```
Public Sub InsertInto(dbName As String, tableName As String, SQLCmd As String, Optional ByVal myFilePath As String = "")
    Dim Conn As New SQLiteConnection(GetConnectionString(dbName, myFilePath))
    Conn.Open()
    Dim Cmd As New SQLiteCommand(Sql, Conn)
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Once you have opened the connection you should be able to execute the query like this:

```
Dim Cmd As New SQLiteCommand(SQLCmd, Conn)
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I'll try doing the connection string in the insert instead of calling the function...that would definitely be strange if that was the issue since I have used the same connection string function to load(the table loads fine using it), create and do bulk inserts for it for almost a year now, just never attempted to do a single insert...

Answer (score 0):

Forgot I have to create a transaction and then commit the transaction in SQLite for it to actually save to the DB...otherwise it just keeps the changes locally and they disappear when you close the program...working as expected now.

```
 Using **transaction = Conn.BeginTransaction()**
            Dim Cmd As New SQLiteCommand(SQLCmd, Conn)
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            **transaction.Commit()**
            Conn.Close()
        End Using
```

EDIT:  This works, but isn't needed I found out...I realized after seeing the value there in the DB and then gone once I ran the program again was that it was writing to the bin/Debug directory and every time I ran the program it overwrote it.  So I pointed it to the proper directory now and it works as expected with my initial code.